# convert lists to customize dictionary in python

Tags: python

i want to convert the list data below into a dictionary.how i

```
['w', 'a', 's', 'x', 'v', 'q']
```

How to convert it to dictionary with keys but values as list:

```
{'w':'w.jpg', 'a':'a.jpg', 's':'s.jpg', 'x':'x.jpg', 'v':'v.jpg', 'q':'q.jpg'}
```

I have a folder of pictures that i want to put them in a dictionary.

Comment: what's the point if the value is just the key plus `.jpg` ?

Comment: then `{a:a+".jpg" for a in ['w', 'a', 's', 'x', 'v', 'q']}`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: whats 'a' in code?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = ['w', 'a', 's', 'x', 'v', 'q']
>>> {e: e+'.jpg' for e in l}
{'w': 'w.jpg', 'a': 'a.jpg', 's': 's.jpg', 'x': 'x.jpg', 'v': 'v.jpg', 'q': 'q.jpg'}
```

Or

```
>>> dict(map(lambda x: (x,x+'.jpg'), l))
{'w': 'w.jpg', 'a': 'a.jpg', 's': 's.jpg', 'x': 'x.jpg', 'v': 'v.jpg', 'q': 'q.jpg'}
```

Or

```
>>> dict(zip(l,[e+'.jpg' for e in l]))
{'w': 'w.jpg', 'a': 'a.jpg', 's': 's.jpg', 'x': 'x.jpg', 'v': 'v.jpg', 'q': 'q.jpg'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `zip` and `list comprehension`:

```
my_images = dict(zip(names,[i+'.jpg' for i in names]))
```

Output:

```
{'w': 'w.jpg', 'a': 'a.jpg', 's': 's.jpg', 'x': 'x.jpg', 'v': 'v.jpg', 'q': 'q.jpg'}
```

Answer (score 1):

if `a` is your key, you could just use `value = a + ".jpg"` to get your value. Creating a dictionary for that isn't very useful.

What would be useful would be to create the dictionary and update it later if you need it. In that case, initialize it with a dictionary comprehension (Python 2.7 and higher):

```
dct = {a:a+".jpg" for a in ['w', 'a', 's', 'x', 'v', 'q']}
```

This dictionary doesn't bring anything new since values can be deduced from keys with a simple addition.

then to change a value to handle special cases:

```
dct['w'] = "new_w.jpg"
```

now the dictionary is useful if you need to handle cases like that. Otherwise avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['w', 'a', 's', 'x', 'v', 'q']

images = {key:key+".jpg" for key in lst}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'a.jpg',
 'q': 'q.jpg',
 's': 's.jpg',
 'v': 'v.jpg',
 'w': 'w.jpg',
 'x': 'x.jpg'}
```